# I am having problems with trying to print email in a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

```
import os.path
import base64
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# Scopes to access Gmail API
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
# Path to the service account key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'
# Email address to search for
QUERY_EMAIL = 'alerts@tradingview.com'
# Define the Gmail API client
def get_gmail_client():
    # Load the service account credentials
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    # Create the Gmail API client
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return service 
# Main function
def main():
    # Get the Gmail API client
    service = get_gmail_client()
    # Define the query to search for incoming emails
    query = f'from: {QUERY_EMAIL}'
    try:
        # Search for the emails matching the query
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
        # Print the contents of the matching emails
        for msg in results.get('messages', []):
            # Get the message ID
            msg_id = msg['id']
            # Retrieve the message data
            message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id).execute()
            # Decode the message payload
            payload = message['payload']
            body = payload['body']['data']
            decoded_body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body).decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded_body)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're making us guess what the problem is.  Show us what the program actually does, and explain what you wanted instead.

Comment: the code has to check for new emails and print them but its having this error            `<HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from%3A+alerts%40tradingview.com&alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.". Details: "[{'message': 'Precondition check failed.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'failedPrecondition'}]">` @JohnGordon

Comment: Does `service.json` contain an access token?  If so, that token may be expired.

Comment: Yes , i just downloaded it for Google cloud

Comment: How long ago did you download it, and how long is the token supposed to last?

Comment: I have downloaded it about a 1 or 2h ago , i am using Service accounts

Comment: It seems that tokens are usually only good for one hour.  So it is likely expired by now.

Answer (score 0):

i change the code to use OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

```
import base64
import os.path
import pickle
import time
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# Scopes to access Gmail API
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

# Location of the credentials file
CREDS_FILE = 'token.pickle'

# Redirect URL for OAuth2 authentication
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080'

# Define the Gmail API client
def get_gmail_client():
creds = None

# Check if we already have valid credentials
if os.path.exists(CREDS_FILE):
    with open(CREDS_FILE, 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no valid credentials, prompt the user to authorize the app
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open(CREDS_FILE, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

# Create the Gmail API client
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

return service

# Main function
def main():
# Get the Gmail API client
service = get_gmail_client()

# Define the query to search for incoming emails
query = 'from: alerts@tradingview.com'

try:
    # Search for the emails matching the query
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()

    # Print the contents of the matching emails
    for msg in results.get('messages', []):
        # Get the message ID
        msg_id = msg['id']

        # Retrieve the message data
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id).execute()

        # Decode the message payload
        payload = message['payload']
        body = payload['body']['data']
        decoded_body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body).decode('utf-8')

        print(decoded_body)

except HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

now the script is running but when i chose the account i am having these Erros h has not completed the Google verification process. The app is currently being tested, and can only be accessed by developer-approved testers. If you think you should have access, contact the developer.
If you are a developer of h, see error details.
Error 403: access_denied

Request details: access_type=offline response_type=code redirect_uri=http://localhost:50035/ state=fphiIU4GKhDemgzQ8NqXvDx07zPYpS client_id=... scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Comment: format your code.. for readability.!